# Remove directory path from list using python and place all files name in list

Tags: python

I have a path named `C:/Users/alias/Desktop/abc tool/001/sampleData`.

And I also have a list:

```py
list1 = ['C:/Users/alias/Desktop/abc tool/001/sampleData/abc.ppt', 'C:/Users/alias/Desktop/abc tool/001/sampleData/xxx.docx','C:/Users/alias/Desktop/abc tool/001/sampleData/ddd.pptx']
```

I want to get only files name such as `abc.ppt`, `xxx.docx`, or `ddd.pptx` in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can do this is using the `os` module:

```
import os

list1 = ['C:/Users/alias/Desktop/abc tool/001/sampleData/abc.ppt', 'C:/Users/alias/Desktop/abc tool/001/sampleData/xxx.docx','C:/Users/alias/Desktop/abc tool/001/sampleData/ddd.pptx']

filenames = [os.path.split(path)[1] for path in list1]

print(filenames)

>>>> ['abc.ppt', 'abc.ppt', 'abc.ppt']
```

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) on `os.path` for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply with list comprehension one line like so:

```
list2 = [x.split('/')[-1] for x in list1]
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("/mydir"):
    if file.endswith(".ppt", ".docx", ".pptx"):
         # Then what you want to do with the files after
```

Might need to tweak it a bit, I can't recall if you can assign multiple extensions on the .endswith arguments off the top of my head. But you can try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

list1 = ['C:/Users/alias/Desktop/abc tool/001/sampleData/abc.ppt', 'C:/Users/alias/Desktop/abc tool/001/sampleData/xxx.docx','C:/Users/alias/Desktop/abc tool/001/sampleData/ddd.pptx']

filenames = [os.path.split(path)[1] for path in list1]

print(filenames)

>>>> ['abc.ppt', 'abc.ppt', 'abc.ppt']
```

This is worked for me. Thanks :)